# How to get the test package to indicate the caller where the test failed?

Tags: go, testing

I am wrapping testing.Error in a func like so:

In checks.go

```golang
func NoError(t *testing.T, err error, message ...string) {
        if err != nil {
            t.Error(message)
        }
}
```

In my test file, say, my_test.go, I have something like this:

```golang
func TestThis(t *testing.T){
    err := someFuncWithError(...)
    NoError(t, err, "error found")
}
```

When an error happens, t.Error() indicates that the error happened in checks.go and not the line in my_test.go.  I can see why that happens. **How do I make it so that NoError(...) prints the line which threw the error in the my_test.go?** I.e. The way it behaves if I were to call t.Error() in my_test.go.

IOW, I get:

```
    checks.go:33: some test failed
```

What I want:

```
    my_test.go:12: test failed here
```

Things I tried:

calling runtime:

```
        _, f, l, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
        t.Errorf("%s:%d %s, in %s", f, l, "some error", t.Name())
```

But that still resulted in t.Error() printing something like "checks.go:12".  Increasing the skip param in runtime.Caller() didn't help.

I also looked at how to set the depth in the testing suite, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`t.Helper()`](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#T.Helper) function to indicate that your helper function is, well, a helper function.

From the Godoc:

> `func (c *T) Helper()`
>
> Helper marks the calling function as a test helper function. When printing file and line information, that function will be skipped. Helper may be called simultaneously from multiple goroutines.

Example:

```golang
func NoError(t *testing.T, err error, message ...string) {
    t.Helper()
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(message)
    }
}
```